# what is the valid http request that can be used within a prestop hook?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

According to the below documentation, the line "HTTP - Executes an HTTP request against a specific endpoint on the Container."

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#hook-handler-implementations

Using preStop hook, I tried to curl to run the following script but it returns nothing. Is the prestop hook limited to use the Http request within the container i.e, localhost?

```
echo "test curl" > /proc/1/fd/1
echo $(curl -s /dev/null http://google.com) > /proc/1/fd/1
echo $(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://google.com) > /proc/1/fd/1
```

Answer (score 2):

No, as I know you are not limited to use `preStop's httpGet` only withing the container. Your cointainer should just have access yo requested url, etc. So in your case you should have access to google.

May I know what exactly you wanna to achieve? Are you trying to redirect `curl` output to `proc with PID:1` ?

Your command perfectly works in containers(that has `curl` itself), when I specify [redirect to STDOUT](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/), I mean `/proc/self/fd/1`

```
kubectl exec -ti curl -- bash
root@curl:/# echo $(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://google.com) > /proc/self/fd/1
301
```

Btw, you can use `exec` instead of `httpGet` in `preStop`, where you can combine `echo` and `curl`

Yaml will be similar to

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: ["curl", "-XPOST", "-s", "http://google.com" > "/proc/1/fd/1"]
```

Please play with `command` and adjust for your needs. I havent tested it, wrote on flight

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Vitalii. Yes, I am trying to redirect curl output to proc with PID:1  so that I can see output of my prestop hook script echo messages in pod logs. While doing that, I observed that when pod is deleted, it goes to prestop hook step, then executes the script and inside the script, I have curl commands to get google.com httpcode and response but they return null.

Comment: How can I pass also body  and headers to this curl request?